# For Each Loops Skips one Cell VBA

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

For some reason the follow loop skips the second cell that I want to copy data to. The variabel cw is just the number for the calendar week that the data correlates to. The X's represent data aleady in the worksheet ws and the Y's represent data that is put into the worksheet before the calendar week. "C" represents what happens with the calendar week variable when it is copied to the second column and the "a" is the point I am using for the offset and the M's represent the month that corresponds with the calendar week but I have yet to implement the part of the macro to do that. So for some reason, even though I am incrementing my offset variable "i" by one it skips the second row and shifts the rest of the C's down. Why would it skip that cell and what suggestions could fix this? There are no other skipped cells in the column aside form the second one.

r1 = the range that I am copying from another worksheet
B7 = the "a" in the diagram below for the destination I want to copy to

```
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
xaxxxxxxxx
mcyyyyyyyy
m yyyyyyyy
mcyyyyyyyy
mcyyyyyyyy
mcyyyyyyyy
mcyyyyyyyy
 c

Dim r As Range
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Dim er As Range
Dim cw As Integer
cw = 42

For Each r In r1
   Set er = ws.Range("B7").End(xlDown).Offset(i, 0)
   er.Value = cw
   i = i + 1
Next r
```

Comment: What's `r1`? Where is B7? It would help if you could make it clear where things are on your sheet by showing, not telling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the first time you do

```
Set er = ws.Range("B7").End(xlDown).Offset(i, 0)
```

`er` become your cell marked with `a`

But the second time End(xlDown) goes on the `c` created before.

The correct code should be:

```
Dim rngStart As Range
Set rngStart = ws.Range("B7").End(xlDown)

For Each r In r1
   Set er = rngStart.Offset(i, 0)
   er.Value = cw
   i = i + 1
Next r
```

Comment: no problem, sometimes just adding an additional variable can save your life :)